# Different results for the same float calculations

Tags: c++, graphics, floating-point, raytracing

In the ray tracing assignment I'm doing, I've to calculate the X-offset of the ray shooting from the camera; the offset calculation goes like this

`FovY` is given as an input; I've remebered to convert it to radians the moment I read the variable.

`OffsetX = tan (FovX / 2) * ((col - (width / 2)) / (width / 2))`

`FovX = tan(FovY / 2) * aspect = tan(FovY / 2) * (width / height)`

Substituting in the original equation and writing the code:

```
float OffsetX = tan(FovY / 2.0f) * (width / height) * ((col - (width / 2.0f)) / (width / 2.0f));
```

gave me an incorrect stretched image, and it took me hours to get it right, which was after finding out that the same equation works after simplifying it.

Final rearranged equation was:

```
float OffsetX = tan(FovY / 2.0f) * (2.0f / height) * (col - (width / 2.0f));
```

I tried debugging and indeed the results were different for both equations.

Would there be any round off error of some sort? Can someone please explain this quirkiness to me?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const float PI = 3.1415f;
    const uint32_t width = 160, height = 120;
    const auto fovy = (30.0f * (PI / 180.0f));
    size_t j = 0;
    auto alpha = (tan(fovy / 2.0f) * (width / height)) * (((j + 0.5f) - (width / 2.0f)) / (width / 2.0f));
    cout << alpha << endl;
    alpha = tan(fovy / 2.0f) * (2.0f / height) * ((j + 0.5f) - (width / 2.0f));
    cout << alpha << endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a complete runnable example showing both ways of computing the result and showing some inputs where the two methods diverge. It will remove a lot of ambiguity from your question.

Comment: Unless you can show two different pieces of code that reproduce whatever behaviour is concerning you, it's hard to help

Comment: It took me a couple of minutes to update it with code, when I found that it's needed; within that some one has down voted this question :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me guess: width and height are integers.

When you do:

```
(width / height)
```

you're getting integer division, which discards the fractional part of the result.  If you instead do:

```
((double)width / height)
```

then the two results will bet nearly identical.

---

as an aside, you can simplify the expression further:

```
tan(FovY / 2.0f) * (2.0f*col - width) / height
```

Comment: It's a common mistake, and psychic debugging is a specialty of mine. =)

Comment: @StephenCanon: Well, that makes it easier for me to file bug reports for you.

Comment: How many Apple engineers are needed to do such an assignment ? ;)